# Second dvc push on AWS Batch using IAM role gets "Unable to locate credentials"

Tags: amazon-s3, boto3, amazon-iam, aws-batch, dvc

I'm running a job on AWS Batch, and this job prepares some data and versions it using `dvc`. Secondly, the job does some transformation generating new data, and it should save this new data using `dvc` again. Also, in this case, i'm setting a instance-profile role to enable the AWS Batch to persist on my S3 bucket.

The first `dvc push` works perfectly. But the second one generates the error `Unable to locate credentials`

I have also changed the script to just touch a file, add to dvc and push, and then repeat the process in with other file, and could replicate the problem.

I have already solved, changing the command `dvc push` to `dvc push especific-file-to-push`, but I'm now trying to understand what is the problem with `dvc push` command without the parameter specifying the file.

Does anybody know?

I'm using dvc `dvc==2.9.5` and `boto3==1.21.21`

Comment: That error message means `boto3` can't find the default access credentials (~/.aws dir). Idk why (unfamiliar with AWS Batch). See https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/configuration.html#using-environment-variables for specific env vars you can set. Or https://dvc.org/doc/command-reference/remote/modify#available-parameters-per-storage-type to override auth in DVC config (use `--local` with secrets).

Comment: Yes, i can reproduce the problem locally setting no credentials, but the problem running on AWS Batch with IAM roles is that, dvc push works when running the first time. At the second time we have this error. And if we use dvc push <file>, the error does not happen.

Comment: Unfortunately this seems more like a AWS Batch question (unless there are more details/context from the DVC project itself that we're not seeing) and I'm not familiar. For now try setting auth env vars before each `dvc push` call, that should also work.

Comment: I think its a combined question since even not doing your recommendation I can `dvc push` when using `dvc push <filename>`. So it proves that the credentials are there. For now, i'm mitigating pushing with the filename, but seems a exoteric error until now

Comment: Hmm... Mind opening a ticket in https://github.com/iterative/dvc.org/issues ? Thanks!

Comment: I can confirm the same behavior on ec2 instances with an IAM role attached.